# Angular2 object cannot set property of undefined

Tags: angular, object, undefined

So I have this little app in Angular2, and I'm trying to define an object. This is the main component.

```
export class ContactComponent  {
    person: {
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
}
constructor(private PeopleService: PeopleService){
}

ngOnInit(){

this.PeopleService.fetchData().subscribe(
    data=> {
        this.person.firstname=data.results[0].name.first;
        console.log(this.person.firstname);
    });
  }
}
```

Then in the console log I get:

> Cannot set property 'firstname' of undefined

I can't figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

You are just defining the type of `person` here (the colon stands for type annotations eg:`propertyName:Type`) :

```js
person: {
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
}
```

What you have done here is telling the compiler that `person` is an object literal with 2 string properties `firstname` and `lastname`. It defines what can be store in that property, not what it contains.

You should assign a value first, otherwise, it will be `undefined`

```js
interface Person {
    firstname ? : string; // the "?" makes the property optional, 
    lastname ? : string; //  so you can start with an empty object
}
export class ContactComponent {

    person: Person = {}; // initializing with an empty object

    constructor(private PeopleService: PeopleService) {}

    ngOnInit() {

        this.PeopleService.fetchData().subscribe(
            data => {
                this.person.firstname = data.results[0].name.first;
                console.log(this.person.firstname);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you take a look on this https://gyazo.com/2ef08d144e87fc28f83fbfe83d974bf3, i get 50 results from the http request, but the second console.log for [1] does not work. any idea why? It's the same error 'cannot set...'

Comment: of course i wont create manually each entry, i just wanted to check if it works, i also tried with a for

Comment: `this.person=data.results.map(()=>{firstname:item.name.first,lastname:item.name.last})` But I mean if you have issues like this, you probably should not have started with angular 2, maybe something simpler, for a beginner angular 2's learning curve is steep.

Comment: I did it, thanks ! So that's because the array doesn't has a implicit length, right?

Comment: That's because the 2nd entry (array[1]) does not exist yet. It's undefined, not a person, you cannot set a property on undefined...

Comment: @n00dl3 why we should be initializing with an empty object?

Comment: Because OP is accessing ` this.person.firstname` inside `ngOnInit`, if the object was not initialized, there would be an error. Note that depending on the situation you don't need to initialize with an empty Object. But if you access a property without checking if the Object has been defined, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a class and inherit in component. For Example see the below code**

```
       export class Person{

            firstname: string;
            lastname: string;
        }
        export class ContactComponent  {
        person=Person[];
        constructor(private PeopleService: PeopleService){
        }

        ngOnInit(){

        this.PeopleService.fetchData().subscribe(
            data=> {
                this.person.firstname=data.results[0].name.first;
                console.log(this.person.firstname);
            });
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First declare an object of person type on `onInit()`.

```
person p=new person();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly create an object in the component class. ex:

   ```
   employee=new Employee();
   ```
2. Then refer to this `employee` object